# Android Libstreaming: How to improve video quality (Testing in Nexus 5)

Tags: android-layout, video-streaming, libstreaming

I am developing an android application. I am sending **stream** (audio+video) from **Mobile to Wowza.** I am using [Libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library for streaming. **The video quality is too bad**. How can we improve it (atleast some text should be readable.)
In my code if you see I have commented the video quality (bad with mentioned parameters) method. If i uncomment it, It shows the green cover over the video screen.
[image]

And also, is it possible to make quality device independent ?

My streaming code is:

```
mSession = SessionBuilder
            .getInstance()
            .setContext(getApplicationContext())
            .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
            .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
            .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
            //.setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(352, 288, 30, 300000))
            .setCamera(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView).setPreviewOrientation(0)
            .setCallback(this).build();
```

Thanks.